How to get notified whenever there is some chnage or new instance is created in an autoscalinggroup
I am trying write an automation script(in trypscript) upgrade the AMI image, an to do so I will double the number of instances(i.e scalling in an autoscalinggroup), so i get exactly same number of new instances with new AMI image, then i will deploy my applications on newly instances, but i dont know by when the new instaces are ready, is there a notifier of callback inside aws ec2 sdk, or aws autoscaling group
at themoment i am trying to
const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    if (newInstanceIds.length >= currentDesiredNumberOfInstances) clearTimeout(timer)
      const asgAfterUpdate = await getAutoScalingGroup(asgName,credentials,region);
    const allInstances = {}.AutoScalingGroups![0].Instances;
  if (allInstances.length >= myNewScalingSize) clearTimeout(timer)
  }, 10000);

these are the sdk i am trying to use
(@aws-sdk/client-auto-scaling": "^3.635.0",
"@aws-sdk/client-ec2": "^3.620.0"

Why not use instance refresh? just create new AMI update in template and set default version to latest and then start instance refresh with high availability option

You can poll the status of EC2 instances with waitUntilInstanceStatusOk
Something like this :
import { EC2Client, DescribeInstanceStatusCommand, waitUntilInstanceStatusOk } from "@aws-sdk/client-ec2";
import { AutoScalingClient, DescribeAutoScalingGroupsCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-auto-scaling";

const ec2Client = new EC2Client({ region });
const asgClient = new AutoScalingClient({ region });

async function waitForInstances(asgName: string, desiredCount: number) {
    let ready = false;
    while (!ready) {
        const asgResponse = await asgClient.send(new DescribeAutoScalingGroupsCommand({ AutoScalingGroupNames: [asgName] }));
        const instances = asgResponse.AutoScalingGroups?.[0].Instances || [];

        // Filter out instances that are still pending
        const instanceIds = instances.filter(instance => instance.LifecycleState === 'InService').map(instance => instance.InstanceId);

        if (instanceIds.length >= desiredCount) {
            ready = true;
            // Wait for all instances to pass status checks
            for (const instanceId of instanceIds) {
                await waitUntilInstanceStatusOk({ client: ec2Client, maxWaitTime: 300, minDelay: 10 }, { InstanceIds: [instanceId] });
            }
        } else {
            await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 10000)); // Wait 10 seconds before polling again
        }
    }
}

Or as @bhupesh-lad indicates use StartInstanceRefreshCommand
